# Why doesn't text-align:center work?

Tags: html, css

I have created a scrolling new bar, I want to put the content in the bar center,
I defined a css:

```
.myfont {
    font-size: 18pt;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

but `text-align: center` doesn't work, how to write the css? Here is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sstong123/ZKKFU/34/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dude you forgot to use the class http://jsfiddle.net/ZKKFU/35/

```
<div id="newsbar" class="myfont"></div>
```

Comment: I don't know why is this answer voted down?
I used the myfont in <font class="myfont">aaa</font></a>

Comment: dont put the class at the font tag. put it on the div tag with the id newsbar check my answer. the fiddle will show you it works.

Comment: [A better way to do without making any changes to markup. FYI - @Deadpool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970973/why-doesnt-text-aligncenter-work/19971419#19971419)

Comment: markup in this needs to be changed. for one it uses font tag. html5 doesn't support font tag. @NathanLee Coders choice I guess. .

Comment: Yes. OP's choice, but he wants text to be at the center, so just with CSS, it can be achived in what I mentioned above without tampering OP's mark up - @Deadpool

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making any further changes to mark up, you just need to make your class `.myfont` to have a `display:block;`. This will make the div to understand `text-align:center;` to a div with a `width` of 100%.

**For Instance,**

```
.myfont {
    font-size: 18pt;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-align:center;  
    width:100%;
    display:block;

}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKKFU/39/)**

Comment: actually this is the answer.. also he is using a deprecated `font` tag

Comment: True @Mr.Alien, he has a deprecated markup, but never know why is he doing so. The point was he needed it to be centered and display:block; was all he needed to do. Thx aly :)

Answer (score 0):

try to give value of `width` and use `float` it solve your problem :)

```
.myfont {
font-size: 18pt;
padding-bottom: 0px;
text-align:center;
width:100%;
float:left;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKKFU/37/)